# Android text alignment multiple directions

Tags: android, button

I'm creating a list of items, probably in the form of Buttons. The thing is I want basically three text fields on the Button, one left aligned, one slightly to the right of the left aligned, and then one right aligned. How could I do something like that?

Comment: That depends, do you just want to draw text on the screen, or do you want those texts to be real views? For instance, to handle clicks on each of them separately.

Comment: The view does need to accept input in the form of a click and longclick, but the three text fields would be considered one View. There will be multiple one these Views on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the three TextView's in a LinearLayout(to align them) and put an onClick callback on the LinearLayout.

Comment: And then just set the background to a Button? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a layout that uses a system button style which contains 3 text views.
You can use the onClick attribute to define a method to be called when your custom button is clicked.

file: /res/layout/custom_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onCustomButtonClick" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="text 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_1"
        android:text="text 2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="text 3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```